# How to log NHibernate query?

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-nhibernate, nlog

I have an Asp.Net MVC 4 project in VB.Net, which use Fluent Nhibernate, NHibernate and NLog. I want to log the NHibernate queries. I want to save the query at a table in my DB, but it also can be showed in a log file. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: I don't know how to get the NHibernate executed query.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11001810/62024) on how to configure NHibernate to use NLog.

NHibernate will log all queries to the `NHibernate.SQL` logger.